# Add tesseract and Leptonica to Qt

Tags: qt, tesseract, leptonica

I want to use Tesseract and Leptonica in my Qt project. My folder image is below. Please, could you tell me how I can add it? The include and lib files of tesseract and leptonica is the folder same .pro.

```
# LEPTONICA

LEPT_HEADERS = C:\Users\Engineer\ImageToText\include\leptonica
LEPT_LIBS = C:\Users\Engineer\ImageToText\lib
INCLUDEPATH += $${LEPT_HEADERS}
DEPENDPATH += $${LEPT_HEADERS}
LIBS += -L$${LEPT_LIBS} -llept
```

Comment: sorry , I cannot load image for reputation number.

Comment: You should include your `.pro` file in the question. Then, are you trying to use already compiled libs, or do you have sources for these libs, and want to compile them with your Qt project? Also, which OS?

Comment: I use windows7, I did this. My .pro file is :                                                                   # LEPTONICA
LEPT_HEADERS = C:\Users\Engineer\ImageToText\include\leptonica
LEPT_LIBS      = C:\Users\Engineer\ImageToText\lib


INCLUDEPATH +=  $${LEPT_HEADERS}
DEPENDPATH += $${LEPT_HEADERS}
LIBS += -L$${LEPT_LIBS} -llept

Comment: I think you should use escaped backslashes or forward slashe as opposed to single back slashes.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I find a project that run with tesseract and leptonica. And I developed my code on it.